# how a variable declaration works inside a case in switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm having trouble understanding how the switch statement works. The following code works even the value of a is 4. I understand that each case inside a switch statement is not a block with its own local scope but does that mean that the variable x was declared even a is not equal to 2?

```
int a = 2;
switch(a){
     case 2:
            int x = 4;
     case 3:
            x = 5;
     case 4: 
            x  = 7;       
}
```

Comment: As noted in the answer to the other question it boils down to this:  A declaration isn't really "executable" although initialization is. So even if `int x = 4` is never executed, you've still declared a variable x in the scope of the switch. So x will be declared even if case 2 never runs

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1**

```
   int a = 2;
   switch(a){

        case 2:
            int x = 4;
            // executes
        case 3:
             x = 5;
            // executes
        case 4: 
             x  = 7;
            // executes

    }
```

in this **`value of x will be 7 because the switch won't break`** if it find a matching case.

**Case 2**

If you want to stop execution on 2  do the following

```
   int a = 2;
   switch(a){

        case 2:
            int x = 4; // variable declaration works even if case wont match. Validity inside switch for every line of code after this line
            break;
            // executes and break
        case 3:
             x = 5;
            break;
            // executes and break
        case 4: 
             x  = 7;
            break;
            // executes and break
       default:
            // write default case here
    }
```

You need not use `int` in every x because of the scope of the declaration throughout the scope.

The scope of the declaration of a variable in the switch will affect the following statements or line of code in the switch. It's because, if the **variable declaration** it will if the scope is not defined by braces.

**Case 3**

```
   int a = 3;
   switch(a){

        case 2:
            {
                int x = 4;
                break; // u can skip this break to. Then also it will throw error.
                // x is local variable inside this braces
            }
            // executes
        case 3:
             x = 5;
            // error
        case 4: 
             x  = 7;
            // error
        System.out.println(""+x);    


    }
```

In the above case, it will through the error. Because its scope is only in that case.
In this scenario, the scope of a variable is declared inside the braces. so outside that braces, x won't work. Because x is a local variable in that case condition.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question.. if a == 4, then x = 7..  but there must be some error because x is only declared in case 2.. my question is why does it not throw an error..

Comment: The scope of decleartion of a variable in switch will affect the following statements or line of code in switch

Comment: @glennmark this wont throw error.

Comment: do you mean that every variable declaration inside a switch statement is invoked even though they don't fall in the right case?

Comment: @glennmark Yes, if you donot provide braces. That case is provided as example( the failing criteria)

Comment: can you post your explanation as an answer. :)

Comment: @glennmark Can you check the explaination with comment is enough. Else  we can discuss in chat

Comment: @glennmark Hope the answer is helpful. Feel free to ask.

Comment: yeah I understand it now thanks

Comment: there's no need sir

Comment: Itz accidently is gone. Happy coding.